# Is there a way to make a Safari window narrower than the width of all the pinned tabs?

Tags: safari, applications, catalina, tabs, big-sur

I use a **lot** of pinned tabs. So many that the width of all of them is greater than the screen width on my MacBook Pro.

On Catalina if a Safari window got larger than the screen width (typically due to using a VNC-style application on a larger screen), I could make it match the screen width instead by closing and reopening Safari. I then navigate off-screen tabs using the keyboard. This has only worked once for me so far on Big Sur – usually the window opens to at least the width of all the pinned tabs, with a portion of it off-screen.

Regardless, sometimes I would like a Safari window to be smaller than the width of the pinned tabs, for example when taking notes on the other half of the screen.

So, is there any way to make the window narrower than all the pinned tabs, both in Catalina and Big Sur?

Comment: I believe you have reached the minimum limit of an app to be smaller or bigger right? I am asking just to be clear about your question.

Comment: Safari windows normally cannot be made narrower than the combined width of all the pinned tabs in the tab bar. There is also an absolute minimum width for Safari which is what I think you're referring to, but that is not the minimum I have reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari-> Preferences-> Tabs

Then change Tab Layout from Separate to Compact